# Photon 2d game multiplayer lags

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, multiplayer, photon

I have a 2D multiplayer game using Photon where all the movements are made by RigidBody 2d. When both players are connected I can see my opponent movements but they are not smooth. **Last Update Time** variable is set to 0.25.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkCharacter : Photon.MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 realPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Quaternion realRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    public float lastUpdateTime = 0.1f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
         if(photonView.isMine){
            //Do nothing -- we are moving
        }
        else {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, realPosition, lastUpdateTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, realRotation, lastUpdateTime);
        }
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info){
        if(stream.isWriting){
            //This is OUR player.We need to send our actual position to the network
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation); 
    }else{
            //This is someone else's player.We need to receive their positin (as of a few millisecond ago, and update our version of that player.
            realPosition = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            realRotation = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [unity script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

`[Lerp] Interpolates between from and to by the fraction t. This is most commonly used to find a point some fraction of the way along a line between two endpoints (eg, to move an object gradually between those points). This fraction is clamped to the range [0...1]. When t = 0 returns from. When t = 1 returns to. When t = 0.5 returns the point midway between from and to.`

So basically `Vector3.Lerp` returns this:

```
from + ((to - from) * t)
```

As you can see, by calling `Lerp` with the same values, it's always returning the same value, what you should use instead are [`MoveTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) and [`RotateTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html).

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, realPosition, lastUpdateTime * Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, realRotation, lastUpdateTime * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Photon, but I think increasing `lastUpdateTime` should make it appear smoother. Although it would probably be better to instead use the code from the Interpolation section of [this tutorial](http://www.paladinstudios.com/2013/07/10/how-to-create-an-online-multiplayer-game-with-unity/), as it should cope better with slow networks.